# uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON jquery 3 upgrade

Tags: jquery

I am trying to upgrade some old code from jQuery 1.11 to version 3. So the code still functions as its suspose to, but I get this error inconsole, and would like to fix it.

This is the code below.

```
 var updateOutput = function(e)
    {
        var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
            output = list.data('output');
        if (window.JSON) {
            output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
        } else {
            output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
        }
    };

$('.dd').on('change', updateOutput);

updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#json_menu_data')));
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.

serialize is this.

```
    serialize: function()
    {
        var data,
            depth = 0,
            list  = this;
            step  = function(level, depth)
            {
                var array = [ ],
                    items = level.children(list.options.itemNodeName);
                items.each(function()
                {
                    var li   = $(this),
                        item = $.extend({}, li.data()),
                        sub  = li.children(list.options.listNodeName);
                    if (sub.length) {
                        item.children = step(sub, depth + 1);
                    }
                    array.push(item);
                });
                return array;
            };
        data = step(list.el.find(list.options.listNodeName).first(), depth);
        return data;
    },

    serialise: function()
    {
        return this.serialize();
    },
```

Nestable is here

```
$.fn.nestable = function(params)
{
    var lists  = this,
        retval = this;

    lists.each(function()
    {
        var plugin = $(this).data("nestable");

        if (!plugin) {
            $(this).data("nestable", new Plugin(this, params));
            $(this).data("nestable-id", new Date().getTime());
        } else {
            if (typeof params === 'string' && typeof plugin[params] === 'function') {
                retval = plugin[params]();
            }
        }
    });

    return retval || lists;
};
```

Comment: What is `list.nestable('serialize')`?

Comment: I added the serialize code above is that what you mean? There is a lot of code to post here, but basically its a drag and drop Navigation that you can drag into a parent to child relation. Up to 4 levels in total, and move things around to change the order (sort order)

Comment: Are you trying to turn a jQuery object into JSON? That doesn't work because there can be curcular references. I guess some of these were added between 1.11 and 3.x.

Comment: I honestly didn't write much of this code myself. I modified it from something I found years ago. I'm not that good with jQuery yet lol. I'm more of a php sql developer.  So the language you speak as in object to json. not sure what you mean. The postions of the items in the list can be dragged and dropped. and then saved. The php side is where I wrote ajax requests to update the navigation items in the correct order and parent to child. Thats the code I wrote lol.

Basically I take apart the json into an array, and update the database according to the order of the list.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look as bad as I thought. It's not seralizing the whole jQuery object, it's just serializing the objects returned by `.data()`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting circularities from that, unless some other code assigned circular objects to `.data()` of the list elements.

Comment: You need to trace back to where you're setting these data values, and figure out why they're circular and if you can fix it. The necessary information isn't in the code you posted above.